# For a valid chain of deduction in boolean algebra, does the chain of its dual hold as well?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

For example,

> xy + x'z + yz
>
> = xy + x'z + yz(x+x')
>
> = xy + x'z + yzx + yzx'
>
> = xy + xyz + x'z + x'zy
>
> = xy(1+z) + x'z(1+y)
>
> = xy + x'z

Hence xy + x'z + yz = xy + x'z.
Also its dual must hold as well.
(x+y) (x'+z) (y+z)= (x+y) (x'+z)

Could this dual result be derived directly using the dual of the whole chain given above?
The dual of the whole chain is:

> (x+y) (x'+z) (y+z)
>
> = (x+y) (x'+z) (y+z) + xx'
>
> = **(x+y) (x'+z) (y+z+x) (y+z+x')**
>
> = (x+y) (x+y+z) (x'+z) (x'+z+y)
>
> = **(x+y) + (0.z) (x'+z) + (0.y)**
>
> = (x+y) (x'+z)

Point of interest is that the two bold lines does violate precedence of . over +.
Still, since dual of each step holds, is the chain of deduction valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You could see this from seeing common axiom sets for a Boolean Algebra and noting the duality of the axioms.  But, why it works out that way requires deeper digging, because there exist many different axiom sets for a Boolean Algebra.

The reason why it works lies in that there exists an isomorphism between the equational sub-structures (B, +, ') and (B, . , ').

Answer (score 2):

For equations like this, yes.

Note that the "precedence" of $\cdot$ over $+$ is just a convention, and to be perfectly accurate we should write parentheses at all times... except it becomes impossible to read/understand.

---

One small correction, however, the second-last line should be
$$\color{red}{(}( x + y ) + ( 0 \cdot z ) \color{red}{)} \cdot \color{red}{(} ( x^\prime + z ) + ( 0 \cdot y ) \color{red}{)}$$ or perhaps just 
$$\color{red}{(} x + y + ( 0 \cdot z ) \color{red}{)} \cdot \color{red}{(} x^\prime + z + ( 0 \cdot y ) \color{red}{)}.$$

Comment: If you want to be perfectly accurate, you don't have to write parentheses all the time.  You could just adopt Polish notation or Reverse Polish notation instead.  In my opinion, Polish notation such as "F x y" or "F x y z" comes as comprehensible as writing F(x, y) for binary operations or F(x, y, z) for ternary operations.